# Completeness of intrinsication

Tags: reference-request, mg.metric-geometry, metric-spaces

**Lemma.** *Suppose $(X,\rho)$ is a complete metric space and $\hat \rho$ is its induced intrinsic metric. Then $(X,\hat \rho)$ is complete*.

This lemma was essentially proved in [2.3. in [Metric minimizing surfaces revisited](https://arxiv.org/abs/1707.09635)] and I used it in my lectures [1.19. in [Pure metric geometry](https://arxiv.org/abs/2007.09846)].
But it should be known for 80 years or so.

> Do you know an earlier reference?

**Postscript.** Let me summarize the answer of Loreno Heer here. The statement was proved in "Local contractions in metric spaces" by Hu and Kirk (1978). A partial case (if metric defines the same topology) was proved in "Die innere Geometrie der metrischen Räume" by Rinow (1961).

Comment: Any comments on my question https://mathoverflow.net/q/391839/121665?

Comment: A quick search turned up the lemma as a corollary in (Local contractions in metric spaces Authors: Thakyin Hu and W. A. Kirk Journal: Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 68 (1978), 121-124 )  https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1978-068-01/S0002-9939-1978-0464180-2/

They in turn cite W.  Rinow, Die innere Geometrie der metrischen Räume, Springer-Verlag, Berlin, 1961 which uses an additional assumption

Comment: This is the relevant part of Rinow (page 120):  "5. $(R, d)$ sei ein finit bogenverknüpfter Raum ohne Umwege. Ist dann
$(R, d)$ vollständig bzw. finit kompakt, so ist auch $(R, d_i)$ vollständig bzw.
finit kompakt."

Comment: @LorenoHeer I think you found the answer so why don't you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 2):

A quick search turned up the lemma as a corollary in (Local contractions in metric spaces Authors: Thakyin Hu and W. A. Kirk Journal: Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 68 (1978), 121-124 ):

https://ams.org/journals/proc/1978-068-01/S0002-9939-1978-0464180-2

They in turn cite W. Rinow, Die innere Geometrie der metrischen Räume, Springer-Verlag, Berlin, 1961 which uses an additional assumption.

This is the relevant part of Rinow (page 120): "5. (R,d)
sei ein finit bogenverknüpfter Raum ohne Umwege. Ist dann (R,d) vollständig bzw. finit kompakt, so ist auch (R,di) vollständig bzw. finit kompakt."

Comment: Indeed, Hu and Kirk prove the required statement. I am still trying to find  "Fixed point for local radial contractions" by Holme --- maybe he proved it as well. Rinow proves a very partial case --- "Raum ohne Umwege" means essentially that intrinsic metric defines the same topology as the original one --- I do not assume this.

Comment: @AntonPetrunin I tried to find Holmes' article, so far no luck though. The journal is available on amazon though for around 15$ (https://www.amazon.de/Fixed-Point-Theory-Its-Applications/dp/012678650X), not entirely sure the amazon one is the correct one though. Maybe if I have time I go by the university library next week, they have a copy, then I take a photo or scan it.