# Characterizations of metric trees

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, mg.metric-geometry, geometric-group-theory

Let $X$ be a geodesic space. Then the following conditions are equivalent:

- For any $x,y\in X, x \neq y$, there is a unique arc (homeomorphic to the interval $[0,1]$) with endpoints $x$ and $y$.
- No subset of $X$ is homeomorphic to $S^1$.
- $X$ is simply connected and its topological dimension (small inductive) equals $1$.
- Every geodesic triangle is isometric to a tripod.
- $X$ is $0$-hyperbolic in the sense of Gromov.
- Intersection of any two closed balls is a closed ball or an empty set.
- For every Lipschitz maps $\gamma:S^1\to X$ and $\pi:X\to\mathbb{R}^2$,
  $$
  \int_{S^1}(\pi\circ\gamma)^*(x\, dy)=0.
  $$

A metric space that satisfies any of the above equivalent conditions is known as the *metric tree* or an *$\mathbb{R}$-tree*.

The problem is that it is very difficult to find a single place where one could find proofs of such equivalences. Thus my question is:

> **Question.** Is there a single paper that where one would find seld-contained proofs of such characterizations of metric trees? I do not necessarily mean exactly the same characterizations. Just many equivalent characterizations.

I wanted to ask my student to write a survey paper that would cover in particular all such proofs. I think it would be a useful reference for people working in analysis on metric spaces, and for him it would be a good way to learn this material, but if there is already a good reference for such characterizations, then perhaps it would be a pointless task. This is why I am asking that question.

Comment: If you mean PhD student, I don't think it is the right person to ask to write such a survey. In any case, you might look at references in https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1992-334-01/S0002-9947-1992-1081940-X/S0002-9947-1992-1081940-X.pdf (Mayer, Nikiel, Oversteegen, T.AMS 1992)

Comment: @YCor Thank you for the reference. Yes, a PhD student, but I would help him so it would likely be a joint work. I know it is not a task for someone unexperienced, but a good way to learn a lot of topics.

Comment: I'd rather mean that it's not helpful for a PhD student, to find positions afterwards, to publish surveys, priority being publishing original research. On the other hand it's quite classical to write down such "known" things carefully inside a PhD memoir, although it's less than what we generally expect of a "survey".

Comment: @YCor I agree, but he just started and this is a good way to learn how to write and  extract information from the papers. Depending how it goes it might be just a part of his thesis and not a paper. It is not intended to be his research. Just a way to learn. Anyway, I truly hate that people tend to publish useless technical "new" results and rarely try to write useful "service" papers that ar focused on a readable presentation of what is known.

Comment: Culler and Morgan (1987, [behind paywall](https://doi.org/10.1112/plms/s3-55.3.571), thank you LMS) say the first definitions of R-trees are due to Tits and provide some other references.

Comment: "Anyway, I truly hate that people tend to publish useless technical "new" results and rarely try to write useful "service" papers"--- hear, hear.

Comment: on more than one occasion i tried to incorporate some "service" material in my papers, but the reviewers would insist on cutting it out and focus on new results only (and i generally heard a similar sentiment about papers from several people)

Comment: @erz I actually include "service" material in nearly every paper of mine and it is almost always appreciated by the referees. I have an obsession (sort of ocd) about writing  "perfect" papers with all details included and not being boring at the same time. I always spend twice as much time that I should and I write 1.5 times more pages than I could. If a technical lemma is easy to prove in half a page, I prefer to include details rather than to refer the reader to a paper that is difficult to find and difficult to read.  It took me however, 10 years to learn how to do it.

Comment: I follow a similar approach as you describe, but either i still need 10 years of learning, or not everybody agrees with us. In fact I know that the latter is true: some people said as much to me, and I have even read some kind of essay be a mathematician discouraging inclusion of non-new results (although I don't remember if he was actually against it, or this was a warning that this could be bad for acceptance)

Comment: As mentionned a survey of these results isn't really paper-worthy, but I still think it's an excellent exercice for a grad student to work through. I also think this could be a good entry in a math blog or other less formal publication.

Comment: It could be a ggt equivalent of "N different proofs of the infinitude of primes", an article that has been written by math students hundreds of times.

Answer (score 2):

Some equivalent characterizations of metric trees can be extracted from Theorem 8 of the paper "Trees, tight extensions of metric spaces, and the cohomological dimension of certain groups: A note on combinatorial properties of metric spaces" by Dress (1984) [DOI link](https://doi.org/10.1016/0001-8708(84)90029-X). The focus of the theorem is more on subsets of metric trees and injective hulls/tight spans, but the proof is self-contained.

Comment: Since you are an expert in geometric measure theory and topology, do you know if the result https://mathoverflow.net/q/391839/121665 is known? The statement is nice, I think, and I would like to know if it is something new.

Comment: Since you are an expert in metric trees and at some point you had to learn it from scratch, do you think such a survey paper (assuming it is really well written, not just copy and paste) would make sense? I suspect that when writing it, some of the proofs would be modified and presented in a more readable form than the original ones. Just be honest.

Comment: I don't know if the result you linked above is known. I actually would have benefited from such a survey paper at some point, so I think it is a good idea. I couldn't find a single paper that does the trick and collected the results I needed from different sources. Sure, many equivalences are implied by more general results about spaces with upper curvature bounds and contained in the book of Bridson and Haefliger for example, but I think trees are interesting enough to have them singled out with self-contained concise proofs.